# everytime i render my computer permenantly freezes

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I have recently started using blender and have done a few small projects which have rendered well. however, now that i have done a bigger project (a scene with 3 donuts and a cup of coffee) every time i try to render the project my computer freezes and the only way to unfreeze the computer is to unplug it and reboot it. I have looked at other threads, forums and have watched videos to try and solve my problem but i want to try not to loose too much quality (if possible)

(i am using the cycles rendering engine and i am rendering through my GPU)

thanks in advance

Comment: What are your computer's specs?  Computer product name, GPU and CPU types, RAM amount, remaining hard drive space...

Comment: windows 10, 64-bit operating system, processor: Intel(r) Core(TM) i5-9400F CPU, GPU:NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650, 8GB ram, 1 terrabyte free           p.s: sorry it took so long to reply, i didnt see the message

Comment: Welcome to Blender Stack Exchange! If you aren't using the newest version of Blender, try updating it. Also check to see if your graphics card drivers are updated. You can also look for any errors. They may show up at the top left of the screen when rendering, or you can go to Window>toggle system console and then try rendering to see if any errors show up in the console. These kinds of problems can be tricky to track down, so the more information you can give us the better the chances are.

Comment: Nice setup!  As Brenticus said, use the system console to see what errors come up.  You can check to make sure your drivers (including OpenGL) are up to date, but otherwise, it's hard for us to see what could be wrong.

Comment: OMG thanks, i updated my GPU drivers and it worked, i never thaght an update would help a problem such as this lol

Comment: Thank you soooooo much for your help

Comment: [the result](https://imgur.com/t44BsJu)